# How to deploy clickonce version lower than MinVersion

Tags: clickonce

My ClickOnce application manifest have MinVersion property defined.
When i try to install a version of the application which is lower than MinVersion, It is not installing.

Note: I am deploying lower version because of a build rollback.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Try publish a new version (v2) with previous files, and set MinVersion = v2